# Find all positive integer solutions of $ (2x-1)^3 +16 = y^4. $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integer solutions of   $$  (2x-1)^3 +16 = y^4. $$

I  think that there exist  no integral solution for this equation, but I am unable to prove it.

Am I right? Is there any solution to this equation, if no how can I prove it?

My attempts: clearly y is odd, so taking congruence:
RHS is congruent 1 (mod 4), and LHS is congruent 1 or 3 (mod 4).
But this couldn't prove that there's no solution, so I tried taking modulo 3,8,... but got stuck.

Comment: It is in your best interest to show your attempts, whatever they may be.

Comment: Hint: Observe that y must be odd. Then, shift 16 to the R.H.S., factorise, and show that the R.H.S. cannot be a perfect cube (the 3 factored terms should be pairwise coprime).

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(2x-1%5Cright)%5E%7B3%7D%2B16%3Dy%5E%7B4%7D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(2x-1)$ is odd, it follows that $(2x-1)^3$ is odd too. This forces $y^4$ to be odd, i.e. $y$ is odd too.

Rewrite the given equation as:

\begin{align}
(2x-1)^3 & =y^4-16 \\
& = (y^2+4)(y+2)(y-2)
\end{align}

Now, we have the following:
\begin{align}
\gcd(y+2,y-2) & = \gcd(4,y-2) \\
& = 1 \ \text{(Since $y-2$ is odd)}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\gcd(y^2+4,y+2) & = \gcd(y^2-y+2,y+2) \\
& = \gcd(y^2-2y,y+2) \\
&= \gcd(y,y+2) \\
&= \gcd(y,2) \\
&=1
\end{align}

To see that $\gcd(y^2+4,y-2)=1$, note that $\gcd(y^2+4,y^2-4)=\gcd(8,y^2-4)=1.$ But since $y^2-4=(y+2)(y-2)$ and $\gcd(y^2+4,y+2)=1$, we are done.

Hence, all $3$ terms on the R.H.S. of our re-written equation are pairwise coprime. If any term is not a perfect cube, then the product of the three terms is also not a perfect cube (can you see why?), contradicting the fact that the L.H.S. of the equation is a perfect cube. Hence, we must have that all 3 terms are perfect cubes. But this is again impossible, since $y+2$ and $y-2$ cannot both be perfect cubes at the same time (again, can you see why?)

We conclude that there are no positive integer solutions to your equation.

Comment: I just realized the same ideas in this proof work if we simply factored as $(y^2+4)(y^2-4)$ instead. That would be easier.

Comment: 1) Since product of three or more co-prime factors, atleast one of them not being a perfect power, cannot be a perfect power, hence in this case it cannot be a perfect cube.                   2) since minimum difference between two perfect cubes is 7.